# What types of individuals correspond to the Alpha, Beta, and Omega personality types?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I don't always pay attention very well when an NPC is talking (In fact, there's one talking to me in the background while I'm typing this question). Usually, it's because I'm thinking about the words the character is saying rather than looking at the screen.  This means that I often miss the personality indicators lighting up to tell me whether a person is an alpha, beta, or omega personality type, and when I get to a speech challenge, I often need to guess to figure out which personality the person has.

It would be nice if there was a way to identify what sort of person I'm talking to based on their words and voice rather than looking at an indicator.  I presume Human Revolution is the kind of game where the designers took something like that into account and made the various personalities fit. With that in mind...

**How can you tell just by listening to a person's dialogue if they are an Alpha, Beta, or Omega?**

Comment: Sometimes listening only to a person's dialogue won't reveal their personality - Chet Wagner is a pure Omega and as far as I know you can only learn that through Detective Chase, who explains that Chet is not exactly a choirboy (indicating the rebellious nature of Omegas).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Think of the personality types this way:

- Alpha = leader, making decisions, respected.
- Beta = follower, doing what they were told, fitting in.
- Omega = outcast/criminal, rebelling against the team hierarchy.

The characters that I've interacted with tend to float between a couple of these, and answering with only a single type during the multiple choices in a conversation may not be the best way to go.

Comment: I took it as the Omega being a follower, and the beta being a narcissist.

Comment: @gnometorule http://animals.howstuffworks.com/mammals/wolf-pack-mentality.htm

Answer (score 2):

Alpha means the first one, as in the leader of a group.
Beta means the second one, as in a follower, second leader, or dictator.
Omega means the last one, such as an outcast, criminal, or a troublemaker.

Comment: This doesn't really add anything that the existing answer hasn't covered, try not to duplicate material :)

Comment: I actually adds the logical connection between letter and type.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is if you can identify personality type based on first few conversations if not the very first one. I can share my observations of typical conversations.

- **ALPHA:** Confident in their speaking, does not show much emotion while speaking... not even while talking about the things he loves, and somewhat of an attention seeker. They need to have an audience at all costs, uses body language like hand movements quite less... but modulates his or her voice.
- **BETA:** Sweet in their speech (even when they don't agree with you regarding something, they will keep their council to themselves). They show emotion while speaking even though the subject may not interest them at all (sometimes faking emotion) only to make you feel comfortable. They don't have any hidden agenda, and avoid attention at all costs. If something spirals up to drama they will apologize profusely even if it was not their fault. Uses body language a lot - more than necessary. They tend to get fidgety, but seems to fake it as if it's cool.
- **OMEGA:** Honest and genuine in their speech but knows how to present it in a respectable way (but nevertheless it sometimes does hurt). Shows genuine excitement in things which interests them and can be blatant as to which they don't like. They can occasionally be *too* honest. They are very comfortable in their own skin. If something spirals out of their control, they will simply walk away without an explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Alpha - leader, egotistical, authoritarian - must be placated/ego stroked

Beta - second in command, strong willed, diplomatic - needs to be persuaded/shown benefits

Omega - soldier, humble, suggestible - will cave in to aggression/"tough love"

Omegas are not outcasts or criminals by default. These are personality types, they don't reflect personal beliefs, social hierarchy, or life choices. A gangster can just as easily be an alpha as a cop can be an omega. Characters are not limited to just one of these types either. There are even some characters that are all three; upon whom the social enhancer's pheromones are useless, but get some interesting responses. You just have to talk to people, watch their expressions, and do a little digging into their background in order to get what you want without the aug. It's not easy. However, there are certain conversation options that are only available if you have the social enhancer, so the aug is worth getting.

You know what, it's a lot easier if you think of it like South Park characters.

Alpha - Cartman

Beta - Stan

Omega - Butters